# What might be preventing my Sling model from registering?

Tags: maven, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, sling, sling-models

My simple Sling model class does not appear in the Apache Sling Console under `/system/console/adapters`, although the bundle does under `/system/console/bundles` (and any service classes I annotate with `@Component` successfully register). I'm using the `ModelsScannerPlugin` plugin to automatically pick up the names of my model class, but it also doesn't appear if I specify the packages manually in `<Sling-Model-Packages>`.

Running `mvn clean install -PautoInstallBundle` ends in `BUILD SUCCESS`, but with the following message:

```
[INFO] --- bnd-maven-plugin:4.0.0:bnd-process (run-bnd) @ core ---
[INFO] Unable to determine whether the meta annotation javax.inject.Qualifier applied to type spinner.slingproject.Job provides bundle annotations as it is not on the project build path. If this annotation does provide bundle annotations then it must be present on the build path in order to be processed
```

**Job.java**

```
package spinner.slingproject;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.ValueMapValue;

@Model(adaptables=Resource.class)
public class Job {

    @ValueMapValue(name="jcr:title")
    String jcrTitle;

    public String getJcrTitle()
    {
        return jcrTitle + " the title";
    }


}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spinner.slingproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Slingproject Core</name>
    <description>Slingproject  core bundle</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions> 
                        <_plugin>org.apache.sling.bnd.models.ModelsScannerPlugin</_plugin>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.bnd.models</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-bnd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://localhost:8080/system/console</slingUrl>
                    <user>*removed*</user>
                    <password>*removed*</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.annotation.versioning</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.query</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallBundle</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-bundle</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I imagine there's either a mistake in my `pom.xml`, or some undocumented incompatibility with `bnd-maven-plugin` (most examples seem to use `maven-bundle-plugin` instead, though the Sling documentation indicates both are compatible).

***EDIT***

Here's the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1535557283139
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Slingproject Core
Bundle-SymbolicName: core
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.201808291541
Created-By: 1.8.0_152 (Oracle Corporation)
Import-Package: org.apache.sling.api.resource;version="[2.8,3)",org.ap
 ache.sling.models.annotations;version="[1.5,2)",org.apache.sling.mode
 ls.annotations.injectorspecific;version="[1.1,2)"
Private-Package: spinner.slingproject
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-4.0.0.201805111645
```

As can be seen from that, there are no entries being created under `Export-Package`.